# How to write array values to columns of same line C#

Tags: c#, loops, csv

I have a loop, which writes the values of an array into a .csv file.  It is appending each line, so it writes the values vertically, however, I would like it to write each value in a different column rather than by line, that way I can filter the content after running the program.

My initial thought was to save all the values in one variable and then just write the variable to the .csv file, but I believe this would fill all values into one cell instead of distributing them to different columns.

I need it to write all of the values of the array on each loop, and then move to the next line on the each time it loops if that makes sense.

```
string pathCleansed = @"myfilename.csv";
                string[] createText = { 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress1, 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress2, 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].SubDivision, 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].City,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].PostalCode,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].MainDivision,
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].confidenceIndicator
                    };
                File.AppendAllLines(pathCleansed, createText, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

These are the current results: [current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwAhL.png)

This is what I would like it to do: [desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E202C.png)

Comment: Use string.Join() : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with CsvHelper package. You can find more information about it here https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper/CsvWriter/.

This helper implements IDisposable so be sure to dispose if it when you're done or wrap it in a using which is more preferred. You will have to provide a writer object to CsvHelper. In the past I've used MemoryStream and StreamWriter.

```
//Headers if you want
csvWriter.WriteField("StreetAddress1");
csvWriter.WriteField("StreetAddress2");
csvWriter.WriteField("subDivision");
csvWriter.WriteField("City");
csvWriter.WriteField("PostalCode");
csvWriter.WriteField("MainDivision");
csvWriter.WriteField("ConfidenceIndicator");
csvWriter.NextRecord();

//Your Loop Here
{
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress1);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress2);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].SubDivision);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].City);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].PostalCode);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].MainDivision);
    csvWriter.WriteField(resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].confidenceIndicator);
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to get the desired results by changing to code to:

```
 string pathCleansed = @"myfilename.csv";
                string[] createText = { 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress1 + "," +
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].StreetAddress2 + "," +
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].SubDivision + "," +
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].City + "," + 
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].PostalCode + "," +
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].PostalAddress[0].MainDivision + "," +
                        resCleansedMulti.TaxAreaResult[0].confidenceIndicator
                     };
                File.AppendAllLines(pathCleansed, createText, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```